# Problem with SharePoint Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have a list and a document library.

I would like my workflow to create a document in the document library when a new list item is created - this works.

I would then like a link to that document to be placed in the 'Associated Document' (hyperlink) field on the list - this is where I am stuck.

I am using the automatically created 'create' variable as below, but am not having any luck. I have also tried to email myself the 'create' variable as a string and the email comes through blank.

How do I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: what are you getting in output variable?

Comment: I created a log as the answer below suggested and it came back empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up creating a second workflow as a workaround solution to this.

For anybody who comes across this in need of help:

1. I added another column in the document library called "Associated List Item" and populate this with the list item ID upon creation.
2. I created a workflow on the document library that would update the item on the list to include the document ID.

Probably not the most efficient way of doing this but it works.

Answer (score 2):

Can you please check by placing log for the variable:create.You need to take one common column between both lists so that you get URL of that create the item.

Comment: I just tried this and it came back empty.